# What is the difference between cyanato, cyanido and cyano? When should i use which?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds

I understand that cyanido is the newly adopted naming in place of cyano but what is cyanato? Can anyone please give examples to illustrate the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cyano- is related to the neutral CN group. Cyanido- is related to the CN- anion. Cyanato- is related to the CNO- anion.